# Access global variable from within a class

Tags: php

I have the following (stripped down) code:

```
<?PHP
    class A {
        function Show(){
            echo "ciao";
        }
    }

    $a = new A();
    $b = new B();

    class B {
        function __construct() {
            $a->Show();
        }
    }
?>
```

With a bit of surprise I cannot access the globally defined $a variable from within the class and I get a *Undefined variable* exception. Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why the surprise? That's a pretty logical variable scope problem there...

I suggest you use either the `global` keyword or the variable `$GLOBALS` to access your variable.

**EDIT:** So, in your case that will be:

```
global $a;
$a->Show();
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['a']->Show();
```

**EDIT 2:** And, since Vinko is right, I suggest you take a look at PHP's manual about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: It is surprising for people accustomed to languages with implicitly inherited scope, like C.

Answer (score 18):

please don't use the global method that is being suggested. That makes my stomach hurt.

Pass $a into the constructor of B.

```
class A {
    function Show(){
            echo "ciao";
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B( $a );

class B {
    function __construct( $a ) {
        $a->Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example though, why wouldnt B extend A?

Comment: @roberthuttinger - it all depends on the relationship between the two classes.

Comment: @robertthuttinger: To expand on what Galen said... Because you may not want B to inherit all of A's methods. In this specific instance, such would yield the same result, but what if you added a constructor method to A that echoed an undesirable value for B? It could create an even larger mess depending on the complexity of the objects.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to define it as a [`global` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) inside the scope of the function you want to use it at.

```
function __construct() {
    global $a;
    $a->Show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
class A {
    public function Show(){
      return "ciao";
    }
}

class B {
    function __construct() {
        $a = new A();
        echo $a->Show();
    }
}

$b = new B();
?>
```