# PHP Function scopes. Trouble coping up with $this vs. global declaration

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access global variable from within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877136/access-global-variable-from-within-a-class)

I want to fortify my knowledge in PHP. But most of the time I have trouble understanding with scopes. I am not sure when to use $this and global declaration keyword on my functions.

This is just an example class I just omitted the __construct()

```
    class myClass{
    public myVariable;

       public function1() {
          $this->myVariable=1;
       }

       public function2(){
          global $myVariable;
          $myVariable=1;
       }
    }
```

Which one is the best approach to use when assigning pre-declared variables inside a function? I am confused somehow by the different books by major publishers in PHP. I am not sure if I am asking the correct question or somehow relevant.

Comment: That's not valid PHP, for one thing. On the `public myVariable`, or the `global $myVariable`.

Comment: Try to avoid using global wherever possible, pass values as function/method arguments if necessary

Answer (score 1):

First off, thats not valid PHP, as Jared Farrish already said. Its `public $myvar` instead of `public myvar`. Variable names *always* begin with `$`.

When you declare a variable in a class:

```
<?php
class A
{
    private $var;
}
```

That variable will be automatically available in all methods if accessed through `$this` (unless the method static, but that is another story). So this would work:

```
<?php
class A
{
    private $var;

    public function foo () {
        // This works 
        $this->var = 1;

        // This is a completely different thing and does not change
        // the contents of A::$var
        $var = 1; 
    }
}
```

Now `global` is a different thing altogether. In PHP, you cant do this:

```
<?php
$global_a = 123;

function myfunc ()
{
    // You wont actually change the value of $global_a with this
    $global_a = 1234;
}
echo $global_a; // still 123
```

You'd think this would work, but global variables aren't automatically available to functions. This is where `global` comes in:

```
<?php 
$global_a = 123;

function myfunc ()
{
    global $global_a;
    $global_a = 1234;
}
echo $global_a; // now it will be 1234
```

I suggest you [read about variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and then you can go on [to OOP in PHP](http://php.net/oop).

PHP is a very quirky language. Just because something works in *most* languages in a certain way doesn't mean it will work in PHP. Most of the times, it wont. So its best to educate yourself as much as possible.

Hope this helps

Comment: oh yes that's invalid sorry I missed the $ sign on the public $myVariable. Just having trouble with scopes. Thanks for spotting it by the way. Thanks for clarifying that in detail. I guess I will stick to $this approach. Your explanation really cleared my doubt about using global and when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Which one is best often depends on the situation. In general it's best to avoid global variables as they bring risks with them of not knowing exactly where they're used.

Using a class variable is a good option if the variable is specific to that instance of the class. (You will have to prefix it with a `$`, though. I.e., `public $myVariable;`).

If the variable is only relevant to the function and instances outside the class, you'd do best to pass it as an reference. This is done by adding an `&` before the `$` in the parameter space. I.e.:

```
public function3(&$myVariable) {
    $myVariable = 1;
}
```

Or alternatively just return the value you wish and set it outside the function. I.e.,:

```
class MyClass {
    public function3() {
        return 1;
    }
}

$myObject = new MyClass();
$myVariable = $myObject->function4();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid passing global variable,as there are many good reasons for that:

1. **Reusing parts of the script is impossible** :
   If a certain function relies on global variables, it becomes almost impossible to use that function in a different context. Another problem is that you can’t take that function, and use it in another script.
2. **Solving bugs is much harder** :
   Tracking a global variable is much harder than a non-global variable.
3. **Understanding the code in a year will be much more difficult** :
   Globals make it difficult to see where a variable is coming from and what it does.

Now your questions:

**Which one is the best approach to use when assigning pre-declared variables inside a function?**
You can pass them **by value or reference** inside a function

**By value**

```
$firstVar = 1;

function abc($firstVar){
    echo $firstVar ; // will give you 1
}
```

**By reference**

```
function abc(&$firstVar){
    $firstVar = 3;   // this will give utility to change that variable even
    echo $firstVar ; // will give you 3
}
```

**Now where to use $this variable:**

$this is used to refer to the current object.
example:

```
class abc{
    private $firstVar;

    function abc(){
        $this->firstVar = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep this approach is what I often use for a long time up to now. Passing them as parameters on the function. It's been a year since I played around with major PHP coding and I forgot some important things. My coding style is classless and I thought I go in depth with classes and OOP so I am reading on "PHP5 and MySQL Bible" and I came across $this which made me confused as I frequently use globals on my scripts even though I don't understand it completely. Thanks for the explanation