# How to load variables from PHP file to another PHP file containing class

Tags: php

Consider the following situation:

I have one php file called 'config.php' like this:

```
<?PHP
$dbIp = "<databseip>";
$dbUte = "<databaseuser>";
$dbPass = "<databasepassword>";
$dbDbase = "<databasename>";
$dbPort = "3636";
?>
```

And another php file called 'player.php' like this:

```
<?PHP

include 'config.php';

class Player {

/* PDO Object */
private $cn;

function __construct() {
    $this->prepareDatabase();
}

private function prepareDatabase() {
    $dbms = 'mysql';

    $dsn = "$dbms:host=$dbIp;port=$dbPort;dbname=$dbDbase"; //HERE I CANNOT GET VARIABLES FROM 'config.php'
    $this->cn=new PDO($dsn, $dbUte, $dbPass); //AND HERE TOO xD
    $this->cn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
}
```

For some reason i cannot access the variables in config.php from player class. Obviously i don't understand something. Can someone explain me the correct way to get those variables?

Comment: They are out of scope!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access global variable from within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877136/access-global-variable-from-within-a-class)

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain me how to reach them? Maybe something like `global $dbUte` inside `prepareDatabase()` function and before `$dns` variable?

Answer (score 2):

They are not in the same scope. To use your variables you have to add it as parameter:

```
<?php

class Player {

/* PDO Object */
private $cn;

function __construct($dbIp, $dbPort, $dbDbase) {
    // Here you pass the parameters to the prepareDatabase method
    $this->prepareDatabase($dbIp, $dbPort, $dbDbase);
}

private function prepareDatabase($dbIp, $dbPort, $dbDbase) {
    $dbms = 'mysql';

    $dsn = "$dbms:host=$dbIp;port=$dbPort;dbname=$dbDbase"; //HERE I CANNOT GET VARIABLES FROM 'config.php'
    $this->cn=new PDO($dsn, $dbUte, $dbPass); //AND HERE TOO xD
    $this->cn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
}

include 'config.php';

// Here you pass the parameters to the constructor
$player = new Player($dbIp, $dbPort, $dbDbase);
```

Comment: Ok, i thank you for your answer but for some reason i need to use construct function in another way, i solved using `global` declaration as you can see in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877136/access-global-variable-from-within-a-class

Comment: @Fumarja this works too, sure. But it sounds more like a hack to me than a solution, and I'm sure that using global variables is not OOP.